# Playing tracks from Apple Music on Mac via iPhone (a la Spotify)?

Tags: iphone, mac, itunes, airplay, apple-music

I have a 2015 MacBook Air running Mojave MacOS.  I have an iPhone running the latest iOS.  I have just recently switched from Spotify to Apple Music.  I liked the feature on Spotify whereby I could search for tracks or podcasts on the Spotify app on my iPhone and have them play in the Spotify app on the Mac.  I'd like to be able to do this with iTunes/Apple Music (and Podcasts, if possible).

With iTunes Remote on my iPhone, I can connect to my Mac and play podcasts that have been already downloaded to the Mac, or items physically in my Mac's library.  I can also control the playback of Apple Music tracks (that is, they aren't in my Mac iTunes library) **already playing on the Mac** -- that is, if I start a track/podcast playing in Apple Music, through iTunes on the Mac, I can skip forward and back within the album or playlist using iTunes Remote on my iPhone.

What I'd like to do is be able to replicate Spotify's behavior: search Apple Music (and Podcasts) on my iPhone and have tracks/podcasts I find there play on my Mac.  That is, not have to search through Apple Music on the Mac to find new tracks and start them playing there, and not have to download podcasts into my library so that iTunes Remote can see them.

I thought about AirPlay.  For this, I would need to update to macOS Monterey, since Mojave doesn't seem to have AirPlay.  I believe I can update my OS to Monterey, although I'd need to clear off disk space to do so, since [Apple indicates](https://support.apple.com/en-us/103260) that MacBook Air 13" early 2015 is compatible (for model identification, I have "MacBookAir7,2", so I believe that that's early 2015).  However the page for [AirPlay compatibility](https://%20https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204689) says AirPlay "works best" with MacBook Airs from 2018 forwards.  Would it work with my Mac?

Would AirPlay work with my Mac?

Is there any way to do what I want without using AirPlay?

(FWIW, I found [Is there Spotify-Connect-Equivalent functionality for Apple Music?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/194207/is-there-spotify-connect-equivalent-functionality-for-apple-music?rq=1) that addressed the same question, but all the information seems dated.)